# importing a cell array from matlab to visual studio (C#)

Tags: c#

I am using visual studio(c#)  to access a simulink model (matlab). I have to read a text file which has a list of strings and numbers of varyinmg length e.g
hello
10929999
world
I have been able to read the file and these variables are available in cell array. now i have three options 1.extract the contents of the file into different variables and get each variable into c# one by one. 2. import that cell array into a string array in c# and then access each element of the string array in c# and 3.convert the cell array to character array(string) and import it to c#

i have succeeded in 1. 
3. seems cumbersome because extracting words from a string will require a loop etc.
2. is the most effective of the options but the problem is that when i use the getworkspacedata option i dont know how to decode object into a string array. it is importatnt to note that it is not an object array but only an object.
and if i use the getvariable command i dont knw how to extract the data. getchararray seems to be working only for a single string. plz help

Comment: Can you show us what you did? A running example? A sample .txt file? Also why don't you just read the .txt file directly into C#. Matlab doesn't seem like a necessary intermediate step.

Comment: ok i will share the details. I am making a gui that has to access a simulink model. the model takes inputs from the text file. so it is kind of easy to decompose the text file in matlab, use its variables in the model and extract variables from matlab to c#. what im trying to do is to import the entire text file data into c# for which as u have suggested the better option is to read the file in c# directly. my bad! thanks for changing the direction!

Comment: the text file has just 3 words.. hello 73856 world..the problem is:the text file is extracted into a cell array (3x1) in matlab.
I can use the getvariable or getworkspacedata command
 
var txt_data = matlab.GetVariable("txt_file_data_matlab_cellarray", "base");                       
/**OR**/
object txt_file_data = null;
matlab.GetWorkspaceData("txt_file_data_matlab_cellarray", "base", out txt_data);  
how do i access data from either the var or object that i have in c# 
which is an equivalent of that cell array in matlab. actually i am still not able to use var or objects in c#